# Connecting click signal to QGraphicsView

Tags: qt4, click, signals

how can I connect a `clicked()` signal to a widget which doesn't seem to handle it (like QGraphicsView). If I try to rely on autoconnect, I get only: `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_xxx_clicked()`

What's the solution for situations like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can reimplement `mousePressEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent` that are inherited from `QAbstractScrollArea`.

Comment: Not only that, but if you really need a signal for those events (to connect elsewhere), you can create a signal in your derived class and emit that signal in the mouseReleaseEvent function.